# Plist with different dictionaries to a struct

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct, plist

I have a `plist` which is an *array of dictionaries*. (root is array).
Each dic have 2 values for sure : `name`, and `icon` as `Strings`.
But some of them have more keys/values, some **don't**.

I am trying to read the array into a structure with :

```
struct Config: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, icon
    }

    let name: String
    let icon: String
}



func functionsStruct() -> Config {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FunctionsList", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
}
```

1. I read a dictionary, how to read an array of dictionaries and how to set up the structure.
2. how to solve it that some dics have keys that others don't ?

Comment: You could make those keys optionals. For example `let someProperty: String?`.

Comment: thanks, the question is how to save array of dictionaries and not an array. can't figure it out.

Comment: Decoding `[Config].self` won't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question :

**I read a dictionary, how to read an array of dictionaries and how to set up the structure.**

```
func functionsStruct() -> [Config] {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FunctionsList", withExtension: "plist")!
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            return try! decoder.decode([Config].self, from: data)
        }
```

As simple as that!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of dictionaries, then you don't need to create your own `Codable` class. Arrays and dictionaries already implements `Codable`.

Just do:

```
func functionsStruct() -> [[String: String]] {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FunctionsList", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode([[String: String]].self, from: data)
}
```

Or use `[[String: Any]]` if the dictionary contains values other than strings.

And then you can access your `name` and `icon` like this:

```
let dicts = functionsStruct()
print(dicts[0]["name"])
```

However, I don't understand why you insist on using a dictionary. I strongly recommend you to stick with a `Codable` struct. You can make optional keys optional:

```
struct Config: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    let optionalKey1: String?
    let optionalKey2: String?
}
```

Their values will be nil if the key does not exist in the plist.

And you need to decode an array of `Config`, instead of just `Config` like you did:

```
return try! decoder.decode([Config].self, from: data)
```